# Selenium in new tabs

Tags: java, selenium, testing, tabs, webdriver

I'm currently working on Selenium tests for a web platform, and I've noticed that the test have problems finding elements on a certain page which will make the test fail. The problem occurs once the test have pressed a button, which opens up a new tab, so my question is whether or not the reason for this happening is due to the webdriver being set to the first tab in the webbrowser or is it something else?

PS.The test has no problem finding elements if the driver is set to start on the second page.

Comment: Are you switching b/w tabs ?

Comment: Are you using java or python as your programming language?

Comment: At this point I only need to switch to the next tab2. I'm doing it in Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggestion sounds correct, to work with the new tab you have to switch driver to it.
This can be simply done like this:

```
public void switchToNewWindow(){
    wait(500);
    List<String> tabs = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(tabs.size()-1));
}
```

to switch back to the first window you can use this:

```
public void switchToFirstWindow(){
    List<String> tabs = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
}
```

In case there are more than 2 tabs you can switch to any tab as shown above switching to tab with the corresponding index.

Answer (score 1):

You have to switch to a new tab, because driver would find only the actual tab WebElements.
Switch to a new tab by using:

```
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.close(); //to close actual tab
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1)); //then switch to new tab
```

Comment: there's no need to close the driver, incase if OP would want to go back to first tab and finish the job there